# OpenCV Python не завершается приложение

Tags: python, opencv

Изучаю библиотеку OpenCV на Python,  и столкнулся со следующей ошибкой. При подключении распознования haarcascade

```py
import cv2 as cv ;
import sys;
faceCascade=cv.CascadeClassifier(cv.data.haarcascades+"haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0, cv.CAP_DSHOW);
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS,24);
i=True
while i:
    ret,img=cap.read()
    gray=cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=1.2,minNeighbors=5,minSize=(20,20))
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    cv.imshow('camera',img)
    if (cv.waitKey(5)==27):
        i=False
cap.release();
cv.destroyAllWindows();
sys.exit(1)
```

Пытался даже через sys закрыть, как видите. Не помогает. Ошибок не возникает. Всё работает, но тупо консоль после виснет даже Ctrl-C не работает

Comment: а выход из цикла работает ? или он так и крутится вечно

Comment: Mr Kruizer отформатируйте ваш код как написано у вас, потому что у меня все в порядке.и по `Esc` выходит без зависания..

Comment: @S.Nick , так и выглядит он у меня. Проблема не в окне, а в процессе. Запуская из консоли это заметно, консоль не реагирует ни на что после закрытия окна.

Comment: @Интик Да, всё работает. Из цикла выходит, окно закрывает, но процесс висит, консоль мертва и не подаёт признаков жизни.